# CanCanCan Ability Viewing in the UI

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cancan, cancancan

I'm working with a large list of abilities for users with different Role types on a rails application. This is with the CanCanCan gem.

It has gotten quite large, and I have non-dev users who want to be able to see a run-down of abilities for different users. How can I represent the existing abilities on a user interface?

i.e.

```
class MyUserAbilityController < ActionController::Base

  def show
    @abilities = current_user.abilities
  end

  def index

    @full_abilities = Hash.new

    Role.all.each do |role|
      @full_abilities[role.name] = role.abilities
    end

  end

end
```

And then pass it along to the view?

Further, although not necessary, is there a way I can dynamically change or alter the CanCanCan abilities from an external source?

I have been playing around with it in the Terminal for now, with an eventual goal to be able to have some basic rule-setting (not creation, but perhaps changing 'can's to 'cannot's) on an admin user interface with radio buttons.

-Schwad

Comment: Not really related to your question, but if this is a newer project you probably should be using the CanCanCan gem.  It is the maintained fork of the now defunct CanCan gem https://rubygems.org/gems/cancancan

Comment: I agree, cancancan is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have decided to develop a gem to solve this answer, it's still very much in development, but soon fit for purpose. It's called CanCanCanSee.

**[Check it out here](https://github.com/schwad/cancancansee)**

It brings you the method `CanCanCanSee.all_abilities` to render a hash of existing abilities and roles.

Also if you want to run a pretty printed version of your abilities from the Terminal (think like you do with `rake routes`) you have `CanCanCanSee.pretty_print_abilities`

Thanks!